Is a creature spell already a permanent?
I have a question, is a creature spell already a permanent?
The situation:
I played against a friend of mine, he played a creature, so I played Essence Scatter to counter it. After that he played Turn Aside, an instant that destroyed a spell, that was against a permanent that he controlled. Is this instant valid or is it against the rules?
I thought it wouldn’t work because the instant that I played, is against a spell not a permanent.

Welcome to the site, do you happen to remember exactly which cards were played here?  The exact wording might matter.

Yes ofc, I played [[Essence Scatte]] and he played [[turn aside]].

Thanks, that helped. I'm still not entirely clear on the order of events though. You played Essence Scatter to counter a creature spell, and your friend responded with Turn Aside to counter your Essence Scatter, is that correct? And you want to know whether that Turn Aside was a legal play?

Yes correct. I’m not quite sure if a creature spell is already a permanent card. So if the turn aside instant was valid. I counted it, but I would love to know the right answer.

I edited the question to remove references to "permanent card". Turn Aside counters a spell that targets a "permanent you control". It does not use the phrase "permanent card", which has a specific meaning that changes the meaning of the question. "Permanent card" refers to any card with a permanent type, such as creature, artifact, etc, in any zone. On the other hand, as the answer says, "permanent" specifically refers to something on the battlefield.

No, your friend's play was not legal. Turn Aside counters spells that target permanents, but a creature spell is still a spell and not a permanent yet.
A spell is (generally) a card on the stack. It remains there until it has resolved or been countered.

112.1. A spell is a card on the stack. [..]

A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield.

110.1. A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield. A permanent remains on the battlefield indefinitely. A card or token becomes a permanent as it enters the battlefield and it stops being a permanent as it’s moved to another zone by an effect or rule.

A spell is never a permanent, and a permanent is never a spell.
Essence Scatter targets spells, never permanents. Since Turn Aside can only target spells that target certain permanents, it can't target Essence Scatter and your friend's play was illegal.

Thank you. Now I know the right answer.

It might be worth noting that a creature card is still a permanent card, and a creature spell is a permanent spell, though neither is a permanent outside the battlefield.

@MatthewJensen technically true but that was only a confusion of terms. It being a creature card has no relevance to the question and would only muddy the waters.
